# failed to load assembly microsoft.data.edm in web 8.5 tridion migration from 2013 sp1

Tags: web8.5, discovery-service

we are migrationg from 2013 sp1 to web 8.5 , however we are not able to fetch anything from tridion content delivery. we have added 8.5 dd4t provider dll and removed 2013 one, added new tridion prefixed dlls, removed ambient data reference in web.config, added discovery service to app settings. we have checked discovery service storage config and it seems correct and the page is also in the broker.

While debugging, it seems taxonomies are getting null from broker
[image]

i can see the taxonomies are published , while going in to the discovery service logs it is not able to find reference of microsoft.data.edm assembly

[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's few things you can try:

1. Check your Post Build event to make sure no Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll
   file is being copied manually to bin folder.
2. Make sure other packages don't have dependency to Microsoft.Data.Edm . Easy way to
   do this is by looking at your package.config files.
3. Uninstall WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.Data.Edm packages. Then install
   again and make sure you only install the stable version.